TypeScript error message on new angular project
I'm following this guide for a new angular setup on my Windows Server 2022 Standard VM.  This seems to happen on multiple projects. When I try and run the sample app, I get this error.
ng serve --open
Application bundle generation failed. [2.461 seconds]

X [ERROR] File 'src\app\app.config.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/main.ts:2:26:
      2 │ import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
        ╵                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Ensure the file is part of the TypeScript program via the 'files' or 'include' property.


X [ERROR] File 'src\app\app.component.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/main.ts:3:29:
      3 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
        ╵                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Ensure the file is part of the TypeScript program via the 'files' or 'include' property.

I tried adding  "preserveSymlinks": true to angular.json as per this but that didn't fix it.
Here's my version info:
Angular CLI: 17.3.5
Node: 20.12.2
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.3.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.5
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.5
@schematics/angular             17.3.5
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.4

Adding tsconfig.app.json as requested.
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

UPDATE: based on Aluan Haddad ask I edited the tsconfig.app.json file and now it works.  Thanks!
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/app/app.config.ts",
    "src/app/app.routes.ts",
    "src/app/app.component.ts"


Add the tsconfig.app.json
